# Different coloring of single references only within bibliography (not text) with natbib, nocite and bibsection

Tags: bibliographies, color, natbib

Dear LaTeX support community,

After years of finding on-spot answers to many of my problems, I have not found a solution to the very topic, I will present in the following. I was not able to color specific references within multiple bibliographies, given that I need to use `natbib`, `nocite` and `bibsection` in this process.

I know there are shortcomings when using `natbib`, but I still would like to stick to it if there is a solution out there.

I have a syllabus with several sections. Each section has its own `bib` file. Based on this structure, I created a bibliography per section for the syllabus.

I also use these separate `bib` files for another document, in which I do not want any highlighting through colors, hence I cannot simply highlight those references in the respective `bib`file.

I prepared a MWE for a syllabus with a single section and `bib`file. Naturally, I have more of these sections, files and references.

I would need a solution which lets me flexibly (!) highlight different references with different colors. Let's say: reference 1 in red, reference 2 in blue and the last one without coloring.

Here is the MWE for the overall document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\title{MWE for different coloring of single references with \texttt{natbib}, \texttt{nocite} and \texttt{bibsection}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}

\begingroup % group and next command relaxes pages break
\let\clearpage\relax
\include{MWEsec}

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Here is the MWE for a single section included in the overall document with `include`:

```
\section{Introduction}

\nocite{Valentino:2014}
\nocite{Wood:2018}
\nocite{Hoeffler:2018}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{mwe}
```

And finally an exemplary `bib` file:

```
@article{Valentino:2014,
author = {Valentino, Benjamin A.},
title = {Why We Kill: The Political Science of Political Violence against Civilians},
journal = {Annual Review of Political Science},
volume = {17},
number = {1},
pages = {89-103},
year = {2014},
doi = {10.1146/annurev-polisci-082112-141937}
}

@article{Wood:2018,
author = {Elisabeth Jean Wood},
title ={Rape as a Practice of War: Toward a Typology of Political Violence},
journal = {Politics \& Society},
volume = {46},
number = {4},
pages = {513-537},
year = {2018},
doi = {10.1177/0032329218773710}
}

@article{Hoeffler:2018,
author = {Anke Hoeffler},
title = {Security and development: Shifting the focus to interpersonal violence},
journal = {The Economics of Peace and Security Journal},
volume = {13},
number = {1},
year = {2018},
doi = {10.15355/epsj.13.1.12}
}
```

Ideally, this results in something similar to this:
[image]